# Angular2 to export/download json file

Tags: javascript, json, angular, download, export

I am using angular 2. I want to give functionality to download JSON file.

Like i have response with res = {bar : foo} then i want to create json file which will contain this response which can be download on button/anchor click.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a data URL and assign it to `<a [href]="myDataUrl">` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs. You can just look up any JavaScript answer that explains it, it's the same in Angular.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It was simpler than expected.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    generateDownloadJsonUri() {
        var theJSON = JSON.stringify(this.resJsonResponse);
        var uri = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:text/json;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(theJSON));
        this.downloadJsonHref = uri;
    }
```

in the template include

```
<a class="btn btn-clear" title="Download JSON" [href]="downloadJsonHref" download="download.json"></a>
```

Comment: How or when is generateDownloadJsonUri() called

Comment: I have used on constructor because i had `this.resJsonResponse` ready. you should call it after you have Json Response ready.

Comment: It downloads html file for me, instead of json data

Comment: May be you should try with Blob.

Comment: I didn't add the download attribute to <a> and was struggling to find out why its not working.That's needed!

Answer (score 20):

Pure JavaScript will do the job.

```
downloadJson(myJson){
    var sJson = JSON.stringify(myJson);
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', "data:text/json;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(sJson));
    element.setAttribute('download', "primer-server-task.json");
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click(); // simulate click
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had some problems when my json was so big, I added a Blob object in the Ankur Akvaliya answer and it works!!

```
generateDownloadJsonUri() {
    let theJSON = JSON.stringify(this.resJsonResponse);
    let blob = new Blob([theJSON], { type: 'text/json' });
    let url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let uri:SafeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
    this.downloadJsonHref = uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DomSanitizer:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html

Import statement is needed:

```
import {enter code here DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

generateDownloadJsonUri() {
    var theJSON = JSON.stringify(this.resJsonResponse);
    var uri = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:text/json;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(theJSON));
    this.downloadJsonHref = uri;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `bypassSecurityTrustUrl()` method from `DomSanitizer`.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  downloadUrl;
  filename = "";
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.generateUrl();
  }

  generateUrl() {
    var res = { appname: "ABCD", appid: 1234 };
    this.filename = res.appname + res.appid;
    var data = JSON.stringify(res);
    var url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
      "data:text/json;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(data)
    );
    this.downloadUrl = url;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<a [href]="downloadUrl" download="{{filename}}.json">Download</a>
```

Note that it is only the code snippet that required for Json file creation and linking with a download link.

Also, you can keep the filename as your wish. Currently, the filename is created using the json data.

If you are interested to check the live demo then you can go with the following link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/download-json-angular-k9fvz?file=/src/app/app.component.ts