# Getting JSON data from a file in NGRX / Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am working off of an existing NgRx/Redux app and new to it (1st app).  I have used a previous answer on SO and having trouble adding it to NgRx effects.

I have the following HTML/Angular in my component:

```html
<div class="block">
  <label id="lbl">File </label>
  <input #fileInput type='file' (change)="_onChange($event)"/>
  <button class="btn btn-sm"  (click)="_uploadFile()">Upload The JSON File</button>
</div>
```

The TS file for the component has:

```js
@Output() uploadFile = new EventEmitter();
    _uploadFile() {
    this.uploadFile.emit();
}
```

The module TS file:

```js
    uploadFile() {
        this.store.dispatch(new PageActions.UploadFile());
    }
```

The action file:

```js
export class UploadFile implements Action {
    readonly type = PageActionTypes.UploadFile;
    constructor(public payload: File) { }
}
```

The effects file:

```js
@Effect()
uploadFile$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PACtions.PageActionTypes.UploadFile),
    map( action => action.payload ),
    // ...
);
```

From a previous SO answer I see this:

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  uploadedData: any;

  onChange(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      const raw = (<FileReader>e.target).result as string;
      const res = JSON.parse(raw);
      this.uploadedData = res;
    }
    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
  }

  uploadFile() {
    console.log(this.uploadedData);
    // this.store.dispatch(new PageActions.UploadFile(this.uploadedData));
  }

}
```

How do I get the onChange($event) and uploadedData to fit into my components, effects, and actions files? My component only has @Output ... stuff and the work happens in the effects file.

**Update**

I have a downloadStateFile like so.

In the component.ts file:

```js
@Output() downloadStateFile = new EventEmitter();
    _downloadStateFile() {
        this.downloadStateFile.emit();
    }
```

This works fine and is passed to the effects file to do the work:

```js
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
    downloadStateFile$ = this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType(TheActionTypes.DownloadState),
       withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromSpace.getTheState)),
       tap(([empty, wspace]) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(wspace));

            // This code below was suggested from the following link:
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360665/angular2-to-export-download-json-file
            var jsonState = JSON.stringify(wspace);
            const clickElement = document.createElement('a');
            clickElement.setAttribute('href', "data:text/json;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(jsonState));
            clickElement.setAttribute('download', "state-file.json");
            clickElement.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(clickElement);
            clickElement.click(); // simulate click
            document.body.removeChild(clickElement);
       })
   );
```

I need the uploadState to do something similar but to take the state in the file and upload the state to the reducer. But first it needs to do all the FileReader in the effect as per the project.

**Update #2**

I only have one component as the FileUploader component created in your mock doesn't exist in mine so I only have:

```html
<div class="block">
  <label id="lbl">File </label>
  <input #fileInput type='file' (change)="_onChange($event)"/>
  <button class="btn btn-sm"  (click)="_uploadFile()">Upload The JSON File</button>
</div>
```

I have this in that .ts file of the html above based on what you provided:

```js
@Output() onChange = new EventEmitter();
    _onChange(event) {
        this.onChange.emit(event.target.files[0]);
    }
```

In your code there is a second layer that is in readFile that passes in the inputFile payload. How do I add that to my above update? Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you post your reducer file?

Comment: How do I get to the reducer is the problem? Once I have the actions back from the effect I will send it to the reducer

Comment: (if I understand your question well) You need to use exhaustMap after your effect. then dispatch new action based on success or failure or anything else you want to do after file is uploaded. Handle new action in new effect with dispatch false.

Comment: @m.akari do you have an example of this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to organize the code fulfilling the above requirement.

- Separating `file-upload` capability to an independent component. Essentially `FileUploader` component would be a dumb component which only communicates via `EventEmitter`.
- Parent component hooks into `upload` event and dispatches appropriate action passing the data received from `FileUploader` as a payload.
- `store` reducer sets appropriate state based on business logic. Simultaneously, `effect` can be hooked into the same (which simulates an 'API call')

Check out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdhmxg) mock implementation for the same.

**EDIT**

Based on the new requirements to use `FileReader` in effects, mock implementation has been modified to accommodate this change.

**EDIT 2**

Based on the new requirements to use not use `store` and simply utilize the effects, another `Injectable` can be introduced which is backed by `Subject` which then provides a way to communicate across `component` and `effects`. Sample code is updated in mock implementation.

Comment: I need it not to be just angular but NgRx! It needs to have the side effects and reducer. The mock you provided doesn't.

Comment: It has everything. `app.state.ts` has the reducer, `app.effects.ts` has the effects and `app.component.ts` has the NGRX bindings

Comment: For the sake of this existing project, I want/need to have the ofChange, uploadData(?), and uploadFile in the effect. Can that be done? That is what I am looking for. So the FileReader I want in the effect. This is the way the project implemented things (not me). Actions just take in inputs and pass outputs.

Comment: See my downloadState updates above on how we need the pattern done with this project.

Comment: Thanks. getting closer. I uplated my question above with another detail about the inputFile payload. Learning a lot. Thanks.

Comment: If you have only 1 layer, then simply `dispatch` the store action instead of raising another event. Meaning to say, remove the `OnChange` eventemitter and modify `_onChange` function to  - function _onChange(event) { this.store.dispatch({
      type: 'BEGIN_FILE_READ',
      payload: {
        inputFile: event.target.files[0]
      }
    }) };

Comment: is there anyone to dispatch like above without doing this.store.dispatch to the effect with the payload? just curious for learning this

Comment: I want to get the app.component.ts emit code to pass stuff without a store to the effect and then get the uploaded data into the store

Comment: @cdub -  Check out the latest edits. Essentially, you'll have to introduce another service in between.